# polynomial long division minus of a minus clarification

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, divisibility, inverse

I have an example of polynomial long division below.  The sixth line down says $32x + 10$.  I thought it would say 16x instead of 32x.  I think I understand why:  line five is "$-12x^2 -24x$."  Since this is subtracted from the line above it ($-12x^2 +8x + 10$), "$-12x^2 -24x$" changes signs and becomes "$12x^2 +24x$."  So is minus a minus ($-(-24x)$) the reason why the difference/subtraction on line six is 32x instead of +8x minus 24x?  The line $-12x^2 -24x$, when subtracted becomes $12x +24x$, is that right?  Here is the problem as transcribed from Carolyn Wheater's McGraw Hill 2010 "Practise Makes Perfect - Algebra" book:

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
3x^2 - 6x  + 16  \\[-3pt] 
2x + 4 \enclose{longdiv}{6x^3 + 0x^2 + 8x + 10} \\[-3pt] 
\begin{align}
       \underline{6x3 +12x^2}\phantom{2} \\[-3pt]
                -12x^2 + 8x + 10  \\[-3pt]   
       \underline{-12x^2 - 24x}\phantom{2} \\[-3pt]
                32x + 10  \\[-3pt]
       \underline{32x + 64}\phantom{2} \\[-3pt]
                -54  \\[-3pt]
       {}
\end{align}
\end{array}
$$

Also, the MathJax tutorial and people who posted (esp. David K and David Cervone) was very helpful.  But I could not figure out how to line up the various steps/levels of arithmetic both under the long-division sign and to the right in the comments.  How do I line up the $x^2$'s under the $x^2$'s, the x's under the other x's, etc.   Also I had wanted to include the Explanations (side comments) from the book I got this from on the side.   I can do that using hline and some other examples I found, but it never lined up  neatly for me. Below in the lefthand column are the expressions from the long division above, in the righthand column are Wheater's commentaries that I had wanted to include above but they made the unlined up example above more garbled.  How do I make the two columns line up neatly?  If MathJax specific questions go somewhere else, please let me know where.

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
3x^2 - 6x  + 16  \\[-3pt] 
2x + 4 \enclose{longdiv}{6x^3 + 0x^2 + 8x + 10} \\[-3pt] 
\begin{align}
       \underline{6x3 +12x^2}\phantom{2} \\[-3pt]
         \underline{-12x^2 +8x + 10} & \hbox{(-12x^2 \div 2x = -6x)} \\[-5pt]
    4 | 500 \\ 
       \underline{-12x2 -24\phantom{00}} & \hbox{($-6x times 2x +4$)} \\
                 32x +10\phantom{0} & \hbox{($32x \div 2x = 16$)} \\
       \underline{\phantom{0}32x +64\phantom{0}} & \hbox{($16 times 2x + 4$)} 
                -54  \\[-3pt]
       {}
\end{align}
\end{array}
$$

thanks,

Al

Comment: Yes, I find alot of people easily get confused here.  Subtracting a negative number is like addition.

Comment: If you want a simple *rule*, here’s what I was taught in my high school (in an earlier geological era): to subtract, just change the sign and add. In your example of $$-12x^2+8x+10$ minus $-12x^2-24x$, you change the latter to $12x^2+24x$, and add that to $-12x^2+8x+10$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you understand polynomial division pretty well. Just make sure everything is neat and aligned, otherwise it is a nightmare to salvage. Below is the division you have posed rewritten:

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
3x^2-6x+16\\[-3pt]
2x+4 \enclose{longdiv}{6x^3+0x^2+8x+10} \\[-3pt]
-\underline{(6x^3+12x^2)\phantom{2}\phantom{2}\phantom{2}\phantom{2}\phantom{2}\phantom{2}\phantom{2}~}\\
-12x^2+8x+10 \\
\underline{-(-12x^2-24x)\phantom{2}\phantom{2}~~} \\
32x+10\\
\underline{\phantom{2}\phantom{2}\phantom{2}\phantom{2}\phantom{2}\phantom{2}\phantom{2}\phantom{2}-(32x+64)} \\
-54
\end{array}
$$

I tried to align the numbers using \phantom{2} and ~. But in the font the $x^2$ is larger than a $x$, so it is much harder to align perfectly. I tried adding comments in the long division by using \tag{...} but it recognises the array as a whole object, so you can't choose which line to put the tag. Hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: Thank you all. Since posting, what works best for me is to rewrite the product a second time to the right: -12x^2 - 24x    **-(12x^2 -24x)**.   Then I cross out each sign in the lefthand version (under the whole long div) so the signs are correct for subtraction.  But the righthand, inside the parens is the original product of multiplying back out, enclosed in parens and noting the minus but not distributing it.  That way the original is always preserved off to the side.   Thanks again to the three of you for your help.  Al